# Problem while passing image and other data in the form of `FormData` with $http.post()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having issue with passing image and other data in the form of `FormData`.

I tried with different approaches as:

1. `var payload = new FormData;` and data are as 
   `payload.append('fees', $scope.fees);`
        `payload.append('lat', $scope.lat);`
        `payload.append('lon', $scope.lon);`
        `payload.append('mer_icon', preIconUrl);`

> ```
> $http.post("APIUrl",payload,{
>   headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
>   transformRequest: angular.identity
> }
> )
> .then(function(response) {
>   console.log(" response: %j ",response);
>   if (response.data.success == 1) {
>                      // success
>                      console.log("success 1 response: %j ",response);
>                      console.log("success 1 response.data: %j ",response.data);
>
>                  } else if (response.data.success == -1){
>                   console.log("success 0 response.data: %j ",response.data);
>                  }else{
>                   console.log("success 0 response.data: %j ",response.data);
>                  }
>
>              }),
> function(response){
>   console.log(" fail response.data: %j ",response.data);
> }
> ```

when I print `payload(FormData)`with browser console, it works. But in server side for `image data(mer_icon)` I get `undefined`.

2.Approach with `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}`, throws multipart boundry error.

3.Approach without headers, same `undefined` I get on server side as in 1st approach I got.

Comment: Check the network request, if it looks good to you .then check the server side ..as I guess your  server side code needs inspection